# Not sure where to put <link> tags When migrating to Next 13 app dir from Next12 pages dir

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to migrate my project from Next v12 to Next v13 app directory and I am not sure where to put the `link` tags in the newer version. In v12 they are placed in the `Head` component in my `_document.js` file like this:

```
<Head>
            {/* Static Css File  */}
            <link rel="stylesheet" href={`${process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASEPATH ?? '' : ''}/css/fontawesome-all.min.css`} />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href={`${process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASEPATH ?? '' : ''}/css/iconfont.css`} />
            <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
            <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossOrigin="true" />
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
</Head>
```

where and how should I use them in my next 13 app dir app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use app/layout.tsx.
Here is an example that will help you.

```
import "./globals.css";
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Ravencoin halving countdown",
  description: "Ravencoin halving countdown",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en" data-theme="mytheme">
      <head>
        <link
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap"
          rel="stylesheet"
        />
      </head>
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Comment: ok this does work and my icons show up. But one thing that is happening is that when I start the server and load the page for the first time it messes up some of my CSS and when I reload it again everything goes all right this is happening only if I add the head tag with the links.

Answer (score 2):

Next has layout.js file inside app directory
as shown below inside head tag you can place your links

```
import './globals.css'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        {/* Static Css File  */}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href={`${process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASEPATH ?? '' : ''}/css/fontawesome-all.min.css`} />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href={`${process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASEPATH ?? '' : ''}/css/iconfont.css`} />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossOrigin="true" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
      </head>
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Comment: ok this does work and my icons show up. But one thing that is happening is that when I start the server and load the page for the first time it messes up some of my css and when I reload it again everything goes all right and this is happening only if I add the head tag with the links

Comment: try putting <Link></Link> and import above    import Link from 'next/link';
also if this link helps:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61059111/external-link-is-not-working-in-next-js-when-you-want-to-use-link-component

Comment: hey @Akanksha I am not talking about <Link> component I am talking about <link> component that that you add in the head of your html to link CSS files and other things

Answer (score 0):

The "DynamicHead" component in Next.js allows you to dynamically add link tags to your application. Just provide a list of URLs in the "links" array, and it handles the rest. It's reusable and perfect for adding dynamic link tags wherever you need them in your pages.

```
import Head from 'next/head';

export default function DynamicHead({ links }) {
  return (
    <Head>
      {links.map((link, index) => (
        <link key={index} rel="stylesheet" href={`${process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASEPATH ?? '' : ''}${link}`} />
      ))}
    </Head>
  );
}
```

After importing the DynamicHead

```
import DynamicHead from '../components/DynamicHead';

export default function YourPage() {
  const dynamicLinks = [
   {/* Your links goes here */}
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <DynamicHead links={dynamicLinks} />
      {/* Your page content goes here */}
    </>
  );
}
```